# classification of irreducible finite dimensional representation of affine hecke algebra of type A

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, p-adic-groups

Let $H_{n}$ be the affine Hecke algebra with parameter q, where q is not root of unity.
The classification of irreducible finite dimensional representations has been given by Kazhdan-Lusztig in terms of geometric data..   I wonder in the case of type A,  is there any classification in terms of  concrete combinatoric?

The reason I ask this question is that,  for degenerate affine Hecke algebra in type A,  all finite dimensional represetnations can be parametrized by  two sequences of complex numbers,
$\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n) $, $\mu=(\mu_1,\mu_2,\cdots,\mu_n) $, such that , $\lambda$ abnd $\mu$ satifisy some simple combinatorics conditions.

It is well known that affine hecke algebra is closely related to degenerate affine Hecke algebra.

I hope and expect there should be similar  even the same classifciation in the case type A.

Comment: Yes! The meta-principle is that the difference conditions in the case of degenerate affine Hecke algebra are replaced by the quotient conditions, e.g. $\lambda_i-\lambda_{i+1}=1$ becomes $\lambda_i/\lambda_{i+1}=q.$ Extensive work has been performed on this classification since Kazhdan and Lusztig's original papers.

Comment: @VictorProtsak:  Thank you.  Could you give some related reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done in Orellana-Ram, `[Affine braids, Markov Traces and the category O](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401317)'. The answer is essentially the same as for the degenerate affine Hecke algebra.